# npm WARN tar ENOENT no such file or directory node_modules/.staging/typescript-8be04997/lib/zh-CN/diagnosticMessages.generated.json

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, package.json

I am running npm install
I have a machine specific package.json and package-lock.json so I cannot change it.
I am on linux
I do not have sudo access
the errors

```
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] static-eval has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=static-eval&version=2.0.2 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] timespan has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=timespan&version=2.3.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] open has the following vulnerability: 1 critical. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=open&version=6.0.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] tunnel-agent has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=tunnel-agent&version=0.4.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hoek has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hoek&version=2.16.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../node_modules/.staging/typescript-8be04997/lib/zh-CN/diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-A4E89MA+kto8giic7zyLU6ZxfXnVeCUlKOyzFsah3+n4BROx4bgonl92KIBtwLud/mIWir8ahqhuhe2by9LakQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-A4E89MA+kto8giic7zyLU6ZxfXnVeCUlKOyzFsah3+n4BROx4bgonl92KIBtwLud/mIWir8ahqhuhe2by9LakQ== but got sha512-x1FIOIOdtF5FC5f7q1galS64Nd4mtcgjdIPX7tV7NkNPotDdmov1DjLrAuGTEFme+0R8N2plqO29pp9IEUXb5Q==. (7879388 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

the log

```
30346 verbose stack Error: sha512-A4E89MA+kto8giic7zyLU6ZxfXnVeCUlKOyzFsah3+n4BROx4bgonl92KIBtwLud/mIWir8ahqhuhe2by9LakQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-A4E89MA+kto8giic7zyLU6ZxfXnVeCUlKOyzFsah3+n4BROx4bgonl92KIBtwLud/mIWir8ahqhuhe2by9LakQ== but got sha512-x1FIOIOdtF5FC5f7q1galS64Nd4mtcgjdIPX7tV7NkNPotDdmov1DjLrAuGTEFme+0R8N2plqO29pp9IEUXb5Q==. (7879388 bytes)
30346 verbose stack     at Transform.on (/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/node-v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ssri/index.js:275:19)
30346 verbose stack     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
30346 verbose stack     at Transform.emit (events.js:208:7)
30346 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
30346 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
30346 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
30347 verbose [folder where I run npm install]
30348 verbose Linux 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64
30349 verbose argv "/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/node-v8.11.1/bin/node" "/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/node-v8.11.1/bin/npm" "install"
30350 verbose node v8.11.1
30351 verbose npm  v5.6.0
30352 error code EINTEGRITY
30353 error sha512-A4E89MA+kto8giic7zyLU6ZxfXnVeCUlKOyzFsah3+n4BROx4bgonl92KIBtwLud/mIWir8ahqhuhe2by9LakQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-A4E89MA+kto8giic7zyLU6ZxfXnVeCUlKOyzFsah3+n4BROx4bgonl92KIBtwLud/mIWir8ahqhuhe2by9LakQ== but got sha512-x1FIOIOdtF5FC5f7q1galS64Nd4mtcgjdIPX7tV7NkNPotDdmov1DjLrAuGTEFme+0R8N2plqO29pp9IEUXb5Q==. (7879388 bytes)
30354 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I expect npm install to actually work

Comment: "npm WARN tar ENOENT no such file or directory node_modules" is in the title but not the body of the question, please past all the error messages.

Answer (score 19):

After trying many approaches, including upgrading `npm`, what helped in my case was:

- `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

the key is I believe to remove `package-lock.json` along with `node_modules`.

It was most probably related to switching between branches having modules already installed.

Comment: This helped me to solve several bugs after I executed "npm cache clean --force" command.

Comment: it is not recommended to delete package-lock.json

Comment: Your comment worked for me "the key is I believe to remove package-lock.json along with node_modules."

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve that issue by following methods:

1.Ensure dependencies described correctly on package.json

2.Just type npm install and hit Enter.

3.Check issue still exists. and If issue not resolved, continue these methods.

4.type npm cache clean and hit Enter

5.type sudo npm install -g npm and hit Enter.

6.Retry npm install and hit Enter.

Comment: what does npm cache clean actually do

Comment: "npm cache clean" no longer exists in npm from version 5 onwards. A command that may help is "npm cache verify" or to completely delete the cache in npm version 5 onwards run "npm cache clean --force".

Answer (score 1):

.staging is a temporary npm folder, where the modules are temporarily saved while they are being downloaded, if the package.json downloads are still not completed, the created folder remains, until the installation is complete.

The problem may be lack of space on your hard drive.